# How to position and anchor text in a QGraphicsScene?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

so i have this little code snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

from PyQt5 import (QtWidgets as qtw, QtCore as qtc, QtGui as qtg)
import qdarkstyle
style = qdarkstyle.load_stylesheet_pyqt5()

class Scene(qtw.QGraphicsScene):
    """
    contains data
    """

    gridSize = (10, 10)
    rectSize = 30

    def __init__(self, parent, ):

        super(Scene, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setSceneRect(0, 0, 600, 400)
        self.createGrid(*self.gridSize)

    def createGrid(self, height, width):
        rectSize = self.rectSize

        self.fields = [
                [self.addRect(
                    rectSize*(1+x), rectSize*(1+y), rectSize, rectSize)
                 for x in range(width)]
                for y in range(height)]

        self.column_ids = [
                self.addText(letter) for letter in
                [chr(65 + i) for i in range(self.gridSize[1])]]
        [x.setPos(rectSize*(1.5 + i), rectSize*.5)
         for i, x in enumerate(self.column_ids)]

        self.row_ids = [
                self.addText(letter) for letter in
                [str(i) for i in range(1, self.gridSize[0])]]
        [x.setPos(rectSize*.5, rectSize*(1.5+i))
         for i, x in enumerate(self.row_ids)]


class View(qtw.QGraphicsView):
    """
    displays data
    """

    def __init__(self, parent=None, scene=None):

        super(View, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setScene(Scene(self))
        self.setMouseTracking(True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(style)
    widget = qtw.QWidget()
    playerView = View(widget)
    widget.setGeometry(300, 300, 400, 300)
    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It creates a QGraphicScene, adds some rectangles so they form a grid and then writes some text to id the rows and columns of the grid.

When i set the position of the row_id and column_id it seems to be the position of the upper left corner of the bounding box of the text.

What i want is that the center of the textboxes is aligned with the center of the rectangles in a row/column of the grid.

i.e. the result should look something like this:

```
___|_A_|_B_|_C_|_D_|_E_|___
   |   |   |   |   |   |
 1 |   |   |   |   |   |
___|___|___|___|___|___|___
   |   |   |   |   |   |
 2 |   |   |   |   |   |
___|___|___|___|___|___|___
```

But what i get at the moment is more like this:

```
___|__A|__B|__C|__D|__E|___
   |   |   |   |   |   |
   |   |   |   |   |   |
__1|___|___|___|___|___|___
   |   |   |   |   |   |
   |   |   |   |   |   |
__3|___|___|___|___|___|___
```

I searched the documentation for QGraphicsScene.addText and QTextItem to find a way to set the anchor for the setPos method to center or something alike but couldn't find anything.

I probably could just get the size of the bounding box of the textitems and subtract half of the position to get the right result but this seems like a hack and i would prefer to directly position the center of the TextItems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the position of a text item by subtracting the center is not a hack, it's the only (or, at least, the simplest) solution.

As the documentation shows, the item is always positioned with the coordinates set for the top-left corner, as it is for *all* QGraphicsItems (and, actually, all QWidgets).

[image: text item coordinate system]

So, the correct way to position them is to subtract the boundingRect center from the position you want to put the items. I suggest you to avoid list comprehensions like you did: there's no performance benefit, and it makes your code less readable.

```
    self.column_ids = []
    for i in range(self.gridSize[1]):
        letter = chr(65 + i)
        pos = qtc.QPointF(rectSize * (1.5 + i), rectSize * .5)
        item = self.addText(letter)
        item.setPos(pos - item.boundingRect().center())
        self.column_ids.append(item)

    self.row_ids = []
    for i in range(self.gridSize[0]):
        pos = qtc.QPointF(rectSize * .5, rectSize * (1.5 + i))
        item = self.addText(str(i + 1))
        item.setPos(pos - item.boundingRect().center())
        self.row_ids.append(item)
```

Consider that you could also create a subclass of QGraphicsTextItem and override its `setPos` method or (better) create your own method for centering it.

```
class CenteredTextItem(qtw.QGraphicsTextItem):
    def centerAt(self, pos):
        self.setPos(pos - self.boundingRect().center())

class Scene(qtw.QGraphicsScene):
    def createGrid(self, height, width):
        # ...
        for i in range(self.gridSize[1]):
            letter = chr(65 + i)
            pos = qtc.QPointF(rectSize * (1.5 + i), rectSize * .5)
            item = CenteredTextItem(letter)
            self.addItem(item)
            item.centerAt(pos)
            self.column_ids.append(item)

        self.row_ids = []
        for i in range(self.gridSize[0]):
            pos = qtc.QPointF(rectSize * .5, rectSize * (1.5 + i))
            item = CenteredTextItem(str(i + 1))
            self.addItem(item)
            item.centerAt(pos)
            self.row_ids.append(item)
```